# Android Text View

Tags: android

I am creating a pop up window in click event,inside that pop up window there are text view and Button... If i create a Id in XML and set the text by 
TextView txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text)

txt.setText("Message");

I ma getting Null pointer Exception same for Button..

Pls

Comment: Maybe you should stop double posting and think of better question names, come on...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509327/android-text-view
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509511/android-text-view
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509097/android-text-view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

findViewById is relative to the parent.
if you call it from another window (popup) and not from activity, it won't find the R.id.text and return null.

Comment: Here By i post my code pl check it n give me solution...

Comment: I am not clear with ur solution.. Pls tl what can i do for it??

Comment: please either correct your spelling/wording and provide the source code or just see other related questions.